# fmincon optimization with defined Matlab function

Tags: matlab, optimization

Is it possible to use the optimization function `fmincon` with a Matlab defined function?

I wrote a function where I give few constant parameters (real or complex) and for now, every time I change these parameters, the result changes (you don't say).

```
[output1, output2] = my_function(input1,input2,input3,input4)
```

I saw that `fmincon` function allows to find the optimum result with a given constraint. Let's say that I want to find the optimum output acting only on `input1` and keeping constant all the others inputs. Is it possible to define something like

```
fmincon(@(input1)my_function,[1,2],[],mean)
```

for `input1` that goes from 1 to 2 for the best value `mean`, where mean is the mean value of some other results.

I know that is a quite vague question but I'm not able to give a minimum example, since `function` makes a lot of things

The first attept with multiple outputs gave me the error `Only functions can return multiple values.`

Then I tried with only one output and if I use

```
output1 = @(input1)function(input2,input3);
fmincon(@output1,[1,2],[],mean)
```

I get the error

> Error: "output1" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with its use here as the name of a function or command.
>   See "How MATLAB Recognizes Command Syntax" in the MATLAB documentation for details.

With `fmincon(@my_function,[1,2],[],mean)` I get `Not enough input arguments.`

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, show us. Else, shows us your failed attempt. MATLAB defined functions are only different to user defined functions in that they are proprietary and often closed source, there is nothing different programming-wise to something you write.

Comment: I added few attempts

Comment: Your problem doesnt seem to have anything to do wit `fmincon` and its just bad use of MATLAB syntax. you can not use the word `function` as it is reserved. Use something else like `my_fun`. Similarly, anonymous functions ( e.g. `@(input1) sum(input1)`) only output 1 value, so you may need to create a fucntion in a separate file that does what you want. I can not help more without a real example, a real [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input should be used in your function definition - read up on how [anonymous functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) should be written. You don't have to use anonymous functions to define the actual objective function (`myFunction` below), you can use functions in their own file. The key is that **the objective function should return a scalar to be minimised.**

Here is a very simple example, using `fmincon` to find the minima in `myFunction`, based on the initial guess `[1.5,1.5]`.

```
% myFunction is min when x=1,y=2
myFunction = @(x,y) (x-1).^2 + (y-2).^2;
% Define the optimisation function.
% This should take one input (can be an array) 
% and output a scalar to be minimised
optimFunc = @(P) myFunction( P(1), P(2) );

% Use fmincon to find the optimum solution, based on some initial guess
optimSoln = fmincon( optimFunc, [1.5, 1.5] );

% >> optimSoln
% optimSoln =
%     0.999999990065893   1.999999988824129

% Optimal x = optimSoln(1), optimal y = optimSoln(2);
```

You can see the calculated optimum isn't exactly `[1,2]`, but it's within the default optimality tolerance. You can change the options for the `fmincon` solver - read the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).

---

If you wanted to keep `y=1` as a constant, you just need to update the function definition:

```
% We only want solutions with y=1
optimFunc_y1 = @(P) myFunction( P(1), 1 ); % y=1 always
% Find new optimal solution
optimSoln_y1 = fmincon( optimFunc_y1, 1.5 );

% >> optimSoln_y1
% optimSoln_y1 = 
%    0.999999990065893
% Optimal x when y=1 = optimSoln(1)
```

---

You can add inequality constraints using the `A`, `B`, `Aeq` and `Beq` inputs to `fmincon`, but that's too broad to go into here, please refer to the docs.

---

Note that you're using the keyword `function` in a way which is invalid syntax. I've instead used valid variable names for the functions in my demo.